# supervisor:start_child returns child,undefined

Tags: erlang

seem to be running in to an issue when calling add_location

```
-module(test_sup).
-version(1.0).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0,add_location/3]).

-export([init/1]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local,?SERVER}, ?MODULE, no_args).

add_location(SupPid, Spaces, Occupied) ->
    supervisor:start_child(SupPid, child(test_location, [Spaces, Occupied])).

init(no_args) ->
    {ok, {{rest_for_one, 5, 2000}, []}}.

child(Module, Args) ->
    {Module, {Module, start_link, Args},
     permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [Module]}.
```

I call....

```
{_, SupPid} = test_sup:start_link().
{Success, LocRef} = test_sup:add_location(SupPid, 1, 0)
```

But add_location is always returning an error..

```
{child,undefined,test_location,
            {test_location,start_link,[1,0]},
            permanent,brutal_kill,worker,
            [zc_pickup_location]}}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

My Error - The method start_link in test_location was returning something the supervisor didnt understand.